# OpenOffice: Build Stop working

Tags: java, openoffice.org, uno

I am getting following error while trying to create OXT file. Prior to that, OS crashed and thing got closed abruptly.
[image]

I am unable to read what these boxes mean

Comment: I see there are words inbetween those boxes, I believe it reads `ERROR: [context="user"] caught unexpected exception!`...`unopkg failed.` Maybe that means something to you?

Comment: @ug_ yes I believe it is due to system crash but so far could not find way to fix it

Comment: I just looked up the error https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=41656